# Is there a way to sort my Google Script project triggers, on the console?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-for-business

My console currently looks like this, and I expect the number of triggers to increase:

[screencap of my GSuite Developer Hub's project triggers console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMxw6.jpg)

I name most of my projects in a standard manner, to allow for easy sorting. However, I don't seem to be able to sort my triggers according to name, or even of time of creation.

Is there a better way for me to manage my list of project triggers, as appearing on the console?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to customize the Script dashboard, neither can you sort the result by any specific column.